# How to have similar mechanism of center-crop on ExoPlayer's PlayerView , but not on the center?

Tags: android, scale, crop, exoplayer

### Background

We record a video of the user's face, and usually the face is located at the upper half of the video.

Later we wish to view the video, but the aspect ratio of the `PlayerView` might be different than the one of the video, so there needs to be some scaling and cropping.

### The problem

The only way I've found to scale the `PlayerView` so that it will be shown in the entire space it has but keeping the aspect ratio (which will result in cropping when needed, of course) , is by using `app:resize_mode="zoom"` . Here's a sample of how it works with center-crop: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=00574047057406286563 . The more the Views that show the content have a similar aspect ratio, the less cropping is needed.

But this is only for the center, meaning it takes a point of 0.5x0.5 of the video, and scale-crops from that point. This causes many cases of losing the important content of the video.

For example, if we have a video that was taken in portrait, and we have a square PlayerView and want to show the top area, this is the part that will be visible:

[image: PlayerView]

Of course, if the content itself is square, and the views are also square, it should show the entire content, without cropping.

### What I've tried

I've tried searching over the Internet, StackOverflow (here) and on [Github](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/), but I couldn't find how to do it. The only clue I've found is about AspectRatioFrameLayout and AspectRatioTextureView, but I didn't find how to use them for this task, if it's even possible.

I was told ([**here**](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/5394)) that I should use a normal `TextureView` , and provide it directly to `SimpleExoPlayer` using `SimpleExoPlayer.setVideoTextureView`. And to set a special transformation to it using `TextureView.setTransform`.

After a lot of trying what is best to use (and looking at [**video-crop repository**](https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/video-crop) , [**SuperImageView repository**](https://github.com/cesards/SuperImageView) , and [**JCropImageView repository**](https://github.com/omgnuts/JCropImageView) which have examples of scale/crop of ImageView and video), I've published a working sample that seems to show the video correctly, but I'm still not sure about it, as I also use an ImageView that's shown on top of it before it starts playing (to have a nicer transition instead of black content).

Here's the current code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val imageResId = R.drawable.test
    private val videoResId = R.raw.test
    private val percentageY = 0.2f
    private var player: SimpleExoPlayer? = null


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        window.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(0xff000000.toInt()))
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (cache == null) {
            cache = SimpleCache(File(cacheDir, "media"), LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor(MAX_PREVIEW_CACHE_SIZE_IN_BYTES))
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
//        imageView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        imageView.setImageResource(imageResId)
        imageView.doOnPreDraw {
            imageView.imageMatrix = prepareMatrixForImageView(imageView, imageView.drawable.intrinsicWidth.toFloat(), imageView.drawable.intrinsicHeight.toFloat())
//            imageView.imageMatrix = prepareMatrix(imageView, imageView.drawable.intrinsicWidth.toFloat(), imageView.drawable.intrinsicHeight.toFloat())
//            imageView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        playVideo()
    }

    private fun prepareMatrix(view: View, contentWidth: Float, contentHeight: Float): Matrix {
        var scaleX = 1.0f
        var scaleY = 1.0f
        val viewWidth = view.measuredWidth.toFloat()
        val viewHeight = view.measuredHeight.toFloat()
        Log.d("AppLog", "viewWidth $viewWidth viewHeight $viewHeight contentWidth:$contentWidth contentHeight:$contentHeight")
        if (contentWidth > viewWidth && contentHeight > viewHeight) {
            scaleX = contentWidth / viewWidth
            scaleY = contentHeight / viewHeight
        } else if (contentWidth < viewWidth && contentHeight < viewHeight) {
            scaleY = viewWidth / contentWidth
            scaleX = viewHeight / contentHeight
        } else if (viewWidth > contentWidth)
            scaleY = viewWidth / contentWidth / (viewHeight / contentHeight)
        else if (viewHeight > contentHeight)
            scaleX = viewHeight / contentHeight / (viewWidth / contentWidth)
        val matrix = Matrix()
        val pivotPercentageX = 0.5f
        val pivotPercentageY = percentageY

        matrix.setScale(scaleX, scaleY, viewWidth * pivotPercentageX, viewHeight * pivotPercentageY)
        return matrix
    }

    private fun prepareMatrixForVideo(view: View, contentWidth: Float, contentHeight: Float): Matrix {
        val msWidth = view.measuredWidth
        val msHeight = view.measuredHeight
        val matrix = Matrix()
        matrix.setScale(1f, (contentHeight / contentWidth) * (msWidth.toFloat() / msHeight), msWidth / 2f, percentageY * msHeight) /*,msWidth/2f,msHeight/2f*/
        return matrix
    }

    private fun prepareMatrixForImageView(view: View, contentWidth: Float, contentHeight: Float): Matrix {
        val dw = contentWidth
        val dh = contentHeight
        val msWidth = view.measuredWidth
        val msHeight = view.measuredHeight
//        Log.d("AppLog", "viewWidth $msWidth viewHeight $msHeight contentWidth:$contentWidth contentHeight:$contentHeight")
        val scalew = msWidth.toFloat() / dw
        val theoryh = (dh * scalew).toInt()
        val scaleh = msHeight.toFloat() / dh
        val theoryw = (dw * scaleh).toInt()
        val scale: Float
        var dx = 0
        var dy = 0
        if (scalew > scaleh) { // fit width
            scale = scalew
//            dy = ((msHeight - theoryh) * 0.0f + 0.5f).toInt() // + 0.5f for rounding
        } else {
            scale = scaleh
            dx = ((msWidth - theoryw) * 0.5f + 0.5f).toInt() // + 0.5f for rounding
        }
        dy = ((msHeight - theoryh) * percentageY + 0.5f).toInt() // + 0.5f for rounding
        val matrix = Matrix()
//        Log.d("AppLog", "scale:$scale dx:$dx dy:$dy")
        matrix.setScale(scale, scale)
        matrix.postTranslate(dx.toFloat(), dy.toFloat())
        return matrix
    }

    private fun playVideo() {
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this@MainActivity, DefaultTrackSelector())
        player!!.setVideoTextureView(textureView)
        player!!.addVideoListener(object : VideoListener {
            override fun onVideoSizeChanged(width: Int, height: Int, unappliedRotationDegrees: Int, pixelWidthHeightRatio: Float) {
                super.onVideoSizeChanged(width, height, unappliedRotationDegrees, pixelWidthHeightRatio)
                Log.d("AppLog", "onVideoSizeChanged: $width $height")
                val videoWidth = if (unappliedRotationDegrees % 180 == 0) width else height
                val videoHeight = if (unappliedRotationDegrees % 180 == 0) height else width
                val matrix = prepareMatrixForVideo(textureView, videoWidth.toFloat(), videoHeight.toFloat())
                textureView.setTransform(matrix)
            }

            override fun onRenderedFirstFrame() {
                Log.d("AppLog", "onRenderedFirstFrame")
                player!!.removeVideoListener(this)
//                imageView.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(5000).start()
                imageView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }
        })
        player!!.volume = 0f
        player!!.repeatMode = Player.REPEAT_MODE_ALL
        player!!.playRawVideo(this, videoResId)
        player!!.playWhenReady = true
        //        player!!.playVideoFromUrl(this, "https://sample-videos.com/video123/mkv/240/big_buck_bunny_240p_20mb.mkv", cache!!)
        //        player!!.playVideoFromUrl(this, "https://sample-videos.com/video123/mkv/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mkv", cache!!)
        //        player!!.playVideoFromUrl(this@MainActivity, "https://sample-videos.com/video123/mkv/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mkv")
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        player!!.setVideoTextureView(null)
        //        playerView.player = null
        player!!.release()
        player = null
    }

    companion object {
        const val MAX_PREVIEW_CACHE_SIZE_IN_BYTES = 20L * 1024L * 1024L
        var cache: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.cache.Cache? = null

        @JvmStatic
        fun getUserAgent(context: Context): String {
            val packageManager = context.packageManager
            val info = packageManager.getPackageInfo(context.packageName, 0)
            val appName = info.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString()
            return Util.getUserAgent(context, appName)
        }
    }

    fun SimpleExoPlayer.playRawVideo(context: Context, @RawRes rawVideoRes: Int) {
        val dataSpec = DataSpec(RawResourceDataSource.buildRawResourceUri(rawVideoRes))
        val rawResourceDataSource = RawResourceDataSource(context)
        rawResourceDataSource.open(dataSpec)
        val factory: DataSource.Factory = DataSource.Factory { rawResourceDataSource }
        prepare(LoopingMediaSource(ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(factory).createMediaSource(rawResourceDataSource.uri)))
    }

    fun SimpleExoPlayer.playVideoFromUrl(context: Context, url: String, cache: Cache? = null) = playVideoFromUri(context, Uri.parse(url), cache)

    fun SimpleExoPlayer.playVideoFile(context: Context, file: File) = playVideoFromUri(context, Uri.fromFile(file))

    fun SimpleExoPlayer.playVideoFromUri(context: Context, uri: Uri, cache: Cache? = null) {
        val factory = if (cache != null)
            CacheDataSourceFactory(cache, DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(getUserAgent(context)))
        else
            DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, MainActivity.getUserAgent(context))
        val mediaSource = ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(factory).createMediaSource(uri)
        prepare(mediaSource)
    }
}
```

I had various issues on trying this till I got to the current situation, and I've updated this question multiple times accordingly. Now it even works with the percentageY I talked about, so I could set it to be from 20% of the top of the video, if I wish. However, I still think that it has a big chance that something is wrong, because when I tried to set it to 50% , I've noticed that the content might not fit the entire View.

I even looked at the source code of ImageView ([**here**](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/ImageView.java)), to see how center-crop is used. When applied to the ImageView, it still worked as center-crop, but when I used the same technique on the video, it gave me a very wrong result.

### The questions

My goal here was to show both ImageView and the video so that it will smoothly transition from a static image to a video. All that while having both have the top-scale-crop of 20% from the top (for example). I've published a sample project [**here**](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/ExoPlayerScaleCrop) to try it out and share people of what I've found.

So now my questions are around why this doesn't seem to work well for the imageView and/or video :

1. As it turns out, none of the matrix creations that I've tried work well for either ImageView or the video. What's wrong with it exactly? How can I change it for them to look the same? To scale-crop from the top 20%, for example?
2. I tried to use the exact matrix for both, but it seems each need it differently, even though both have the exact same size and content size. Why would I need a different matrix for each?

---

EDIT: after this question was answered, I've decided to make a small sample of how to use it (Github repository available [**here**](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/ExoPlayerScaleCrop)) :

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Matrix
import android.graphics.PointF
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.TextureView
import android.view.View
import androidx.annotation.RawRes
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.doOnPreDraw
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerFactory
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaSource
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.LoopingMediaSource
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.DefaultTrackSelector
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.*
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.cache.Cache
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.cache.CacheDataSourceFactory
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.cache.LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.cache.SimpleCache
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.VideoListener
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.io.File

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54216273/how-to-have-similar-mechanism-of-center-crop-on-exoplayers-playerview-but-not
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object {
        private val FOCAL_POINT = PointF(0.5f, 0.2f)
        private const val IMAGE_RES_ID = R.drawable.test
        private const val VIDEO_RES_ID = R.raw.test
        private var cache: Cache? = null
        private const val MAX_PREVIEW_CACHE_SIZE_IN_BYTES = 20L * 1024L * 1024L

        @JvmStatic
        fun getUserAgent(context: Context): String {
            val packageManager = context.packageManager
            val info = packageManager.getPackageInfo(context.packageName, 0)
            val appName = info.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString()
            return Util.getUserAgent(context, appName)
        }
    }

    private var player: SimpleExoPlayer? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        if (cache == null)
            cache = SimpleCache(File(cacheDir, "media"), LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor(MAX_PREVIEW_CACHE_SIZE_IN_BYTES))
        //        imageView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        imageView.setImageResource(IMAGE_RES_ID)
    }

    private fun prepareMatrix(view: View, mediaWidth: Float, mediaHeight: Float, focalPoint: PointF): Matrix? {
        if (view.visibility == View.GONE)
            return null
        val viewHeight = (view.height - view.paddingTop - view.paddingBottom).toFloat()
        val viewWidth = (view.width - view.paddingStart - view.paddingEnd).toFloat()
        if (viewWidth <= 0 || viewHeight <= 0)
            return null
        val matrix = Matrix()
        if (view is TextureView)
        // Restore true media size for further manipulation.
            matrix.setScale(mediaWidth / viewWidth, mediaHeight / viewHeight)
        val scaleFactorY = viewHeight / mediaHeight
        val scaleFactor: Float
        var px = 0f
        var py = 0f
        if (mediaWidth * scaleFactorY >= viewWidth) {
            // Fit height
            scaleFactor = scaleFactorY
            px = -(mediaWidth * scaleFactor - viewWidth) * focalPoint.x / (1 - scaleFactor)
        } else {
            // Fit width
            scaleFactor = viewWidth / mediaWidth
            py = -(mediaHeight * scaleFactor - viewHeight) * focalPoint.y / (1 - scaleFactor)
        }
        matrix.postScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, px, py)
        return matrix
    }

    private fun playVideo() {
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this@MainActivity, DefaultTrackSelector())
        player!!.setVideoTextureView(textureView)
        player!!.addVideoListener(object : VideoListener {
            override fun onVideoSizeChanged(videoWidth: Int, videoHeight: Int, unappliedRotationDegrees: Int, pixelWidthHeightRatio: Float) {
                super.onVideoSizeChanged(videoWidth, videoHeight, unappliedRotationDegrees, pixelWidthHeightRatio)
                textureView.setTransform(prepareMatrix(textureView, videoWidth.toFloat(), videoHeight.toFloat(), FOCAL_POINT))
            }

            override fun onRenderedFirstFrame() {
                //                Log.d("AppLog", "onRenderedFirstFrame")
                player!!.removeVideoListener(this)
                imageView.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000).start()
                //                imageView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }
        })
        player!!.volume = 0f
        player!!.repeatMode = Player.REPEAT_MODE_ALL
        player!!.playRawVideo(this, VIDEO_RES_ID)
        player!!.playWhenReady = true
        //        player!!.playVideoFromUrl(this, "https://sample-videos.com/video123/mkv/240/big_buck_bunny_240p_20mb.mkv", cache!!)
        //        player!!.playVideoFromUrl(this, "https://sample-videos.com/video123/mkv/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mkv", cache!!)
        //        player!!.playVideoFromUrl(this@MainActivity, "https://sample-videos.com/video123/mkv/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mkv")
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        imageView.doOnPreDraw {
            val imageWidth: Float = imageView.drawable.intrinsicWidth.toFloat()
            val imageHeight: Float = imageView.drawable.intrinsicHeight.toFloat()
            imageView.imageMatrix = prepareMatrix(imageView, imageWidth, imageHeight, FOCAL_POINT)
        }
        playVideo()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        if (player != null) {
            player!!.setVideoTextureView(null)
            //        playerView.player = null
            player!!.release()
            player = null
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        if (!isChangingConfigurations)
            cache?.release()
    }

    fun SimpleExoPlayer.playRawVideo(context: Context, @RawRes rawVideoRes: Int) {
        val dataSpec = DataSpec(RawResourceDataSource.buildRawResourceUri(rawVideoRes))
        val rawResourceDataSource = RawResourceDataSource(context)
        rawResourceDataSource.open(dataSpec)
        val factory: DataSource.Factory = DataSource.Factory { rawResourceDataSource }
        prepare(LoopingMediaSource(ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(factory).createMediaSource(rawResourceDataSource.uri)))
    }

    fun SimpleExoPlayer.playVideoFromUrl(context: Context, url: String, cache: Cache? = null) = playVideoFromUri(context, Uri.parse(url), cache)

    fun SimpleExoPlayer.playVideoFile(context: Context, file: File) = playVideoFromUri(context, Uri.fromFile(file))

    fun SimpleExoPlayer.playVideoFromUri(context: Context, uri: Uri, cache: Cache? = null) {
        val factory = if (cache != null)
            CacheDataSourceFactory(cache, DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(getUserAgent(context)))
        else
            DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, MainActivity.getUserAgent(context))
        val mediaSource = ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(factory).createMediaSource(uri)
        prepare(mediaSource)
    }
}
```

Here's a solution for ImageView alone, if needed:

```
class ScaleCropImageView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : AppCompatImageView(context, attrs) {
    var focalPoint = PointF(0.5f, 0.5f)
        set(value) {
            field = value
            updateMatrix()
        }
    private val viewWidth: Float
        get() = (width - paddingLeft - paddingRight).toFloat()

    private val viewHeight: Float
        get() = (height - paddingTop - paddingBottom).toFloat()

    init {
        scaleType = ScaleType.MATRIX
    }

    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
        updateMatrix()
    }

    override fun setImageDrawable(drawable: Drawable?) {
        super.setImageDrawable(drawable)
        updateMatrix()
    }

    @Suppress("MemberVisibilityCanBePrivate")
    fun updateMatrix() {
        if (scaleType != ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX)
            return
        val dr = drawable ?: return
        imageMatrix = prepareMatrix(
                viewWidth, viewHeight,
                dr.intrinsicWidth.toFloat(), dr.intrinsicHeight.toFloat(), focalPoint, Matrix()
        )
    }

    private fun prepareMatrix(
            viewWidth: Float, viewHeight: Float, mediaWidth: Float, mediaHeight: Float,
            focalPoint: PointF, matrix: Matrix
    ): Matrix? {
        if (viewWidth <= 0 || viewHeight <= 0)
            return null
        var scaleFactor = viewHeight / mediaHeight
        if (mediaWidth * scaleFactor >= viewWidth) {
            // Fit height
            matrix.postScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, -(mediaWidth * scaleFactor - viewWidth) * focalPoint.x / (1 - scaleFactor), 0f)
        } else {
            // Fit width
            scaleFactor = viewWidth / mediaWidth
            matrix.postScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, 0f, -(mediaHeight * scaleFactor - viewHeight) * focalPoint.y / (1 - scaleFactor))
        }
        return matrix
    }
}
```

Comment: the issue might be: https://storage.googleapis.com/stateless-35-202-129-15/2018/07/16433840-vertical-meme.jpg

Comment: @MartinZeitler Yes I know. I checked the wrong variables. I meant to check the degrees and for some reason checked the width and height... Still, I have issues with the ImageView and the container of the video. Please, if you know why this occurs, let me know.

Comment: barely based upon the images posted, I'd suspect this subject to be related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180804/how-to-get-the-aspect-ratio-of-an-image ...where both, the video aspect ratio and the display (or surface) aspect ratio, need to be taken into account... in order to get a result which looks natural. some combinations of these might require much cropping - or having borders. there should also be a formula for calculating the optimal center-crop. basically it's just two rectangles, in relation to each other.

Comment: @MartinZeitler But I used the exact same technique on the ImageView as I did for the video. Both get the same width&height of the View and the content inside the function.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I think that the video matrix is also incorrect, and not just for the ImageView. I hope I will get a solution for this soon.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The question is how to manipulate an image like [`ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType) but to shift the focus from the center to another location that is 20% from the top of the image. First, let's look at what `CENTER_CROP` does:

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType):

**CENTER_CROP**

> Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or larger than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding). The image is then centered in the view. From XML, use this syntax: `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`.

In other words, scale the image without distortion such that either the width or height of the image (or both width and height) fit within the view so that the view is completely filled with the image (no gaps.)

Another way to think of this is that the center of the image is "pinned" to the center of the view. The image is then scaled to meet the criteria above.

In the following video, the white lines mark the center of the image; the red lines mark the center of the view. The scale type is `CENTER_CROP`.  Notice how the center points of the image and the view coincide. As the view changes size, these two points continue to overlap and always appear at the center of the view regardless of the view size.

[image]

So, what does it mean to have center crop-like behavior at a different location such as 20% from the top? Like center crop, we can specify that the point that is 20% from the top of the image and the point that 20% from the top of the view will be "pinned" like the 50% point is "pinned" in center crop. The horizontal location of this point remains at 50% of the image and view. The image can now be scaled to satisfy the other conditions of center crop which specify that either the width and/or height of the image will fit the view with no gaps. *(Size of view is understood to be the view size less padding.)*

Here is a short video of this 20% crop behavior. In this video, the white lines show the middle of the image, the red lines show the pinned point in the view and the blue line that shows behind the horizontal red line identifies 20% from the top of the image. (Demo project is on [GitHub](https://github.com/Cheticamp/DemoAlternateCrop).

[image]

Here is the result showing the full image that was supplied and the video in a square frame that transition from the still image. .

[image]

**MainActivity.kt** 
`prepareMatrix()` is the method that does the work to determine how to scale/crop the image. There is some additional work to be done with the video since it appears that the video is made to fit the `TextureView`as a scale type "FIT_XY" when it is assigned to the `TextureView`. Because of this scaling, the media size must be restored before `prepareMatrix()` is called for the video

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val imageResId = R.drawable.test
    private val videoResId = R.raw.test
    private var player: SimpleExoPlayer? = null
    private val mFocalPoint = PointF(0.5f, 0.2f)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        window.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(0xff000000.toInt()))
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (cache == null) {
            cache = SimpleCache(File(cacheDir, "media"), LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor(MAX_PREVIEW_CACHE_SIZE_IN_BYTES))
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        //        imageView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        imageView.setImageResource(imageResId)
        imageView.doOnPreDraw {
            imageView.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX
            val imageWidth: Float = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, imageResId)!!.intrinsicWidth.toFloat()
            val imageHeight: Float = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, imageResId)!!.intrinsicHeight.toFloat()
            imageView.imageMatrix = prepareMatrix(imageView, imageWidth, imageHeight, mFocalPoint, Matrix())
            val b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, imageResId)
            val d = BitmapDrawable(resources, b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true))
            val c = Canvas(d.bitmap)
            val p = Paint()
            p.color = resources.getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark)
            p.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
            val strokeWidth = 10
            p.strokeWidth = strokeWidth.toFloat()
            // Horizontal line
            c.drawLine(0f, imageHeight * mFocalPoint.y, imageWidth, imageHeight * mFocalPoint.y, p)
            // Vertical line
            c.drawLine(imageWidth * mFocalPoint.x, 0f, imageWidth * mFocalPoint.x, imageHeight, p)
            // Line in horizontal and vertical center
            p.color = resources.getColor(android.R.color.white)
            c.drawLine(imageWidth / 2, 0f, imageWidth / 2, imageHeight, p)
            c.drawLine(0f, imageHeight / 2, imageWidth, imageHeight / 2, p)

            imageView.setImageBitmap(d.bitmap)
            imageViewFull.setImageBitmap(d.bitmap)
        }
    }

    fun startPlay(view: View) {
        playVideo()
    }

    private fun getViewWidth(view: View): Float {
        return (view.width - view.paddingStart - view.paddingEnd).toFloat()
    }

    private fun getViewHeight(view: View): Float {
        return (view.height - view.paddingTop - view.paddingBottom).toFloat()
    }

    private fun prepareMatrix(targetView: View, mediaWidth: Float, mediaHeight: Float,
                              focalPoint: PointF, matrix: Matrix): Matrix {
        if (targetView.visibility != View.VISIBLE) {
            return matrix
        }
        val viewHeight = getViewHeight(targetView)
        val viewWidth = getViewWidth(targetView)
        val scaleFactorY = viewHeight / mediaHeight
        val scaleFactor: Float
        val px: Float
        val py: Float
        if (mediaWidth * scaleFactorY >= viewWidth) {
            // Fit height
            scaleFactor = scaleFactorY
            px = -(mediaWidth * scaleFactor - viewWidth) * focalPoint.x / (1 - scaleFactor)
            py = 0f
        } else {
            // Fit width
            scaleFactor = viewWidth / mediaWidth
            px = 0f
            py = -(mediaHeight * scaleFactor - viewHeight) * focalPoint.y / (1 - scaleFactor)
        }
        matrix.postScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, px, py)
        return matrix
    }

    private fun playVideo() {
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this@MainActivity, DefaultTrackSelector())
        player!!.setVideoTextureView(textureView)
        player!!.addVideoListener(object : VideoListener {
            override fun onVideoSizeChanged(width: Int, height: Int, unappliedRotationDegrees: Int, pixelWidthHeightRatio: Float) {
                super.onVideoSizeChanged(width, height, unappliedRotationDegrees, pixelWidthHeightRatio)
                val matrix = Matrix()
                // Restore true media size for further manipulation.
                matrix.setScale(width / getViewWidth(textureView), height / getViewHeight(textureView))
                textureView.setTransform(prepareMatrix(textureView, width.toFloat(), height.toFloat(), mFocalPoint, matrix))
            }

            override fun onRenderedFirstFrame() {
                Log.d("AppLog", "onRenderedFirstFrame")
                player!!.removeVideoListener(this)
                imageView.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000).start()
                imageView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }
        })
        player!!.volume = 0f
        player!!.repeatMode = Player.REPEAT_MODE_ALL
        player!!.playRawVideo(this, videoResId)
        player!!.playWhenReady = true
        //        player!!.playVideoFromUrl(this, "https://sample-videos.com/video123/mkv/240/big_buck_bunny_240p_20mb.mkv", cache!!)
        //        player!!.playVideoFromUrl(this, "https://sample-videos.com/video123/mkv/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mkv", cache!!)
        //        player!!.playVideoFromUrl(this@MainActivity, "https://sample-videos.com/video123/mkv/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mkv")
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        if (player != null) {
            player!!.setVideoTextureView(null)
            //        playerView.player = null
            player!!.release()
            player = null
        }
    }

    companion object {
        const val MAX_PREVIEW_CACHE_SIZE_IN_BYTES = 20L * 1024L * 1024L
        var cache: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.cache.Cache? = null

        @JvmStatic
        fun getUserAgent(context: Context): String {
            val packageManager = context.packageManager
            val info = packageManager.getPackageInfo(context.packageName, 0)
            val appName = info.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString()
            return Util.getUserAgent(context, appName)
        }
    }

    fun SimpleExoPlayer.playRawVideo(context: Context, @RawRes rawVideoRes: Int) {
        val dataSpec = DataSpec(RawResourceDataSource.buildRawResourceUri(rawVideoRes))
        val rawResourceDataSource = RawResourceDataSource(context)
        rawResourceDataSource.open(dataSpec)
        val factory: DataSource.Factory = DataSource.Factory { rawResourceDataSource }
        prepare(LoopingMediaSource(ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(factory).createMediaSource(rawResourceDataSource.uri)))
    }

    fun SimpleExoPlayer.playVideoFromUrl(context: Context, url: String, cache: Cache? = null) = playVideoFromUri(context, Uri.parse(url), cache)

    fun SimpleExoPlayer.playVideoFile(context: Context, file: File) = playVideoFromUri(context, Uri.fromFile(file))

    fun SimpleExoPlayer.playVideoFromUri(context: Context, uri: Uri, cache: Cache? = null) {
        val factory = if (cache != null)
            CacheDataSourceFactory(cache, DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(getUserAgent(context)))
        else
            DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, MainActivity.getUserAgent(context))
        val mediaSource = ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(factory).createMediaSource(uri)
        prepare(mediaSource)
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187157/discussion-on-answer-by-cheticamp-how-to-have-similar-mechanism-of-center-crop-o).

Answer (score 0):

you can use app:resize_mode="zoom" in com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView

Comment: `zoom` may result in a CENTER_CROP behaviour but the original question is on how to crop another part of the video _than_ center.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it by applying transformations on the `TextureView` whose `Surface` is used by ExoPlayer:

```kotlin
player.addVideoListener(object : VideoListener {
    override fun onVideoSizeChanged(
        videoWidth: Int,
        videoHeight: Int,
        unappliedRotationDegrees: Int,
        pixelWidthHeightRatio: Float,
    ) {
        removeVideoListener(this)
        val viewWidth: Int = textureView.width - textureView.paddingStart - textureView.paddingEnd
        val viewHeight: Int = textureView.height - textureView.paddingTop - textureView.paddingBottom
        if (videoWidth == viewWidth && videoHeight == viewHeight) {
            return
        }
        val matrix = Matrix().apply {
            // TextureView makes a best effort in fitting the video inside the View. The first transformation we apply is for reverting the fitting.
            setScale(
                videoWidth.toFloat() / viewWidth,
                videoHeight.toFloat() / viewHeight,
            )
        }
        
        // This algorithm is from ImageView's CENTER_CROP transformation
        val offset = 0.5f // the center in CENTER_CROP but you probably want a different value here
        val scale: Float
        val dx: Float
        val dy: Float
        if (videoWidth * viewHeight > viewWidth * videoHeight) {
            scale = viewHeight.toFloat() / videoHeight
            dx = (viewWidth - videoWidth * scale) * offset
            dy = 0f
        } else {
            scale = viewWidth.toFloat() / videoWidth
            dx = 0f
            dy = (viewHeight - videoHeight * scale) * offset
        }
        setTransform(matrix.apply {
            postScale(scale, scale)
            postTranslate(dx, dy)
        })
    }
})
player.setVideoTextureView(textureView)
player.prepare(createMediaSource())
```

Note that unless you're using `DefaultRenderersFactory` you need to make sure that your video `Renderer` actually calls `onVideoSizeChanged` by for instance creating the factory like so:

```kotlin
val renderersFactory = RenderersFactory { handler, videoListener, _, _, _, _ ->
        // Allows other renderers to be removed by R8
        arrayOf(
            MediaCodecVideoRenderer(
                context,
                MediaCodecSelector.DEFAULT,
                DefaultRenderersFactory.DEFAULT_ALLOWED_VIDEO_JOINING_TIME_MS,
                handler,
                videoListener,
                -1,
            ),
            MediaCodecAudioRenderer(context, MediaCodecSelector.DEFAULT),
        )
    }
```